# Adding ArrayList to ArrayListArrayList

Tags: android

Suppose we have an ArrayListArrayList(String)

```
[[a,b,c,d] , [e,f,g,h]]
```

and an ArrayList(String)

```
[1,2,3]
```

How can we add ArrayList to ArrayListArrayList in position 1 at the end in order to get

```
[[a,b,c,d] , [e,f,g,h,1,2,3]]
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
//pseudocode
List<ArrayList<String>> arraylistarraylist = [[a, b, c, d], [e, f, g, h]];    

List<String> list = Arrays.asList(1,2,3);

arraylistarraylist.get(1).addAll(list);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need a [`add(int, E)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/List.html#add%28int,%20E%29)  method

```
List<ArrayList<String>> dataHolder = new ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>();

List<String> firstData = new ArrayList<String>();
firstData.add("a");
firstData.add("b");
firstData.add("c");
firstData.add("d");

List<String> secondData = new ArrayList<String>();
secondData.add("e");
secondData.add("f");
secondData.add("g");
secondData.add("h");
secondData.add("1");
secondData.add("2");
secondData.add("3");

dataHolder.add(secondData);
dataHolder.add(0, firstData); // insert your List<String> to 0 index position in dataHolder
```

Answer (score 0):

If we name your `ArrayList<ArrayList>` `m` and if we name your `ArrayList` `a`, then you could use

```
m.get(1).addAll(a)
```

Description for this method provided by Oracle here: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html